# p5.js createCanvas not defined error. Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, p5.js

*Problem:*

I am trying to use [p5.js](https://github.com/lmccart/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview) in my simple app, and including it thus:

```
<script src="static/js/p5.js"> </script>
```

*What I've tried:*

If I put a debugger and look in the console, I do get the functions for `p5Color` (for ex) and others. And the script gets loaded on to the page fine. Except `createCanvas` doesn't auto-complete and when used in the page, throws above error.

*Why? How can I work around this?*

Comment: Ahem.. Any comments about why the downvote?

Comment: You were probably downvoted because it's not clear what you're asking. ("Any namespacing issues am not aware of?" - is not really an answerable question.) I edited the question and provided an answer for you... hope it helps!

Comment: @wxactly: It does help.I'll accept the answer. Yeah, my js understanding was lacking to frame the question better then. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

p5.js won't load into "global mode" unless it sees `setup()` or `draw()` defined on the page.

Option 1 - force global mode. (Note that if you do this, `createCanvas()` won't do you much good in the console, since `setup()` will have already run on page load.)

```
<script src="static/js/p5.js"> </script>
<script>
    function setup() {
        //...
    }
</script>
```

Option 2 - use [instance mode](https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html). (This is probably your best bet if you really want to use p5.js from the console.)

```
var s = function( sketch ) {
  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(700, 410);
    //...
  };
};    
var myp5 = new p5(s);
```

Comment: Thanks.  The [P5 Getting Started](https://p5js.org/get-started/) shows these functions but really fails to explain the significance.