# How can I get p5.js to work in an IIFE without using instance mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, p5.js

I am trying to use p5.js in an IIFE. So far, when I try and use the print() method, it works as expected and logs whatever I pass to it in the console log. Here's my code below.

```js
(function () {
    function setup() {
        print("Hello World");
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        new p5();
        setup();
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-uaz5GpnQoE6t5echKlX8P52czvsIGgLPcvlzfvRubLZ1Hp8JemUDnbUiAahbVtPb+jUVrNETuXvAhDDF/N3M4w=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        ></script>
        <title>Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div id="puzzle-container">
                <canvas id="puzzle"></canvas>
            </div>
        </main>

        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can even use the select() method to target an element in the DOM and print it out and it also works. However, when I try to use the createCanvas() function it doesn't seem to work. A default canvas will be generated but it won't have the specified size, or be placed in a specified parent container using the parent() method. I get no errors either, only a warning with this message: "p5.js seems to have been imported multiple times. Please remove the duplicate import."

Is what I'm looking to do possible?

My ultimate goal is to create a namespace and create functions that will be prefixed by the namespace but still be able to use the P5 api methods. Take this code for example:

```
var game = game || {};

(function(ns) {
    var canvasWidth = 480;
    var canvasHeight = 480;

    ns.initGame = function() {
        createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        background(153);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        ns.initGame();
    })
})(game);
```

The HTML related to the code is exactly the same for the HTML provided earlier. The code above will log a message saying: "createCanvas" is not defined in the current scope. So my ultimate question is that, is there a way to achieve my desired outcome in the IIFE without using P5 in instance mode? I want to avoid prefixing P5 functionality with `sketch.` or `p.`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an IIFE without instance mode, use `window.` to prefix the p5 global functions so they're visible to the library:

```js
(() => {
  window.setup = () => {
    createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  window.draw = () => {
    background(`hsl(${frameCount % 360}, 50%, 50%)`);
  };
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

p5 first checks to see whether `setup` or `draw` is defined on the window, then switches to global mode and populates the rest of its API on the window. So if you want to use global mode, you need to at least define `window.setup` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27895716/6243352).

Think of the callback to `setup()` the equivalent of `$(document).ready`, which doesn't wait for p5 to detect and populate its API on the window, or preload assets (if applicable).

Applied to your updated code:

```js
var game = game || {};

(function(ns) {
    var canvasWidth = 480;
    var canvasHeight = 480;

    ns.initGame = function() {
        createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        background(153);
    }

    window.setup = function() { // rather than $(document).ready
        ns.initGame();
    }
})(game);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

If you want to use instance mode, closely follow the [guidelines](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode). `new p5()` is given a callback which is the sketch. Don't call `setup()` or use any non-prefixed global p5 functions or variables.

```js
const p5Sketch = p => {
  // always use p. before any p5 calls

  p.setup = () => {
    p.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  p.draw = () => {
    p.background(`hsl(${p.frameCount % 360}, 50%, 50%)`);
  };
};
const p5Instance = new p5(p5Sketch);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I see you have a `<canvas>` in your sketch. That's generally not necessary--p5 handles canvas management for you.

Comment: In the first example you provided using p5 without instance mode, the only way to access the createCanvas and background functionality would be to have them inside a a function with a window. prefix? I can't access them as they are in a function that doesn't have a window. prefix?

Comment: I want to add that the reason why I'm asking this is because the end goal is to create a namespace for the code, if I'm using p5 in instance mode and don't want to keep leading every function with sketch. prefix and instead have everything tied to the specific namespace that I will use and just use the p5 functions that I need when required in those specific namespace functions.

Comment: p5 doesn't initialize those globals like `createCanvas` and the rest of the p5 API until `setup()`, so you can call them from other functions, but only once p5 loads into global mode and populates all of its API onto the window--that's always the case regardless of the IIFE or not.

Comment: Basically the IIFE example achieves your goal--you can namespace all your data instead of putting it into the global scope. You have to add `window.` to a few of those core p5 functions and that's pretty much the only difference. I like the `p.` prefix--it makes it clear which calls are part of the p5 library and which are part of your code, improving readability.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, the only way to be able to use those API methods like createCanvas, print, etc., I have to wrap all of my code inside the IIFE in a window.setup function, then inside of that I can use the namespace to create my own functions and variables and still be able to call methods like createCanvas inside of them without issue?

Comment: No, you can call `createCanvas()` and `print()` from anywhere, and you can have your own functions outside of the IIFE. It's totally normal global mode p5. The only difference is that declaring `function setup()` (and `preload()`, `draw()`) in the IIFE won't work because it'd be local to the closure, but it needs to be global for p5 to see it. Hence the `window.` prefix to break out of the closure and expose it globally. Like normal p5 global mode, of course, you can't access the p5 API until it's been registered on the window, which happens right before `setup()`/`preload()` are called.

Comment: If you're having trouble with some specific code, please share it so I can more concretely understand and respond to whatever you're trying to implement.

Comment: I updated my question with a code block that shows my intended use scenario that I want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I still don't understand what the issue is. Instead of `ns.initGame`, use p5 functions like `setup()` and `draw()` as shown in my top example. Are you asking how to use p5 without using `draw()`? If so, it should "just work" as long as you wait for `setup()` to run so the global p5 namespace is ready. But 99% of the time, it's best to use the hooks p5 gives you. p5 basically has `$(document).ready(function() {setup()})` already written for you (and it waits for `preload` assets to complete), so you shouldn't need to call an init function explicitly.

Comment: [p5.js createCanvas not defined error. Uncaught ReferenceError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694616/p5-js-createcanvas-not-defined-error-uncaught-referenceerror) may be a duplicate.

Comment: Hopefully my updated answer clarifies how to apply my original answer to your attempt.